Custom Claims Not Included in Token After Local Sign-In in Azure AD B2C Custom Policies
I am new to custom policies for Azure AD B2C and have encountered an issue while working with custom attributes. The custom attributes I have added are being included in the token when a user creates an account (verified using jwt.ms), but they are not present in the token during subsequent sign-ins. I have implemented several of the suggestions from other posts [1], [2], [3], but I have hit a dead end.
Here are the key parts of my policies so far:
Custom Attributes Definition
<ClaimType Id="extension_InternationalAddress">
    <DisplayName>International Address</DisplayName>
    <DataType>boolean</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Your International Address</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>RadioSingleSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <Enumeration Text="Yes" Value="1" SelectByDefault="false" />
        <Enumeration Text="No" Value="0" SelectByDefault="true" />
    </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
<!-- Other custom claims defined here -->

TrustFrameworkBase.xml
Read using object id
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_InternationalAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_suburb" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainrole" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainservicesetting" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>

Read using Email
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
 
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_InternationalAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_suburb" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainrole" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainservicesetting" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

TrustFrameworkPolicy.xml (Sign-Up/Sign-In)
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
        <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
        <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Country" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_InternationalAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_suburb" PartnerClaimType="suburb" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainrole" PartnerClaimType="mainrole" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainservicesetting" PartnerClaimType="mainservicesetting" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="trustFrameworkPolicy" Required="true" DefaultValue="{policy}" PartnerClaimType="tfp" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>

User Journey
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
            <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            </ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>objectId</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
    <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>

AAD-Common
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
    <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureActiveDirectoryProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">{B2C extensions app Object ID}</Item>
        <Item Key="ClientId">{B2C extensions app Client ID}</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>

SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_InternationalAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_suburb" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainrole" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainservicesetting" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>

login-NonInteractive
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
    <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_InternationalAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_suburb" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainrole" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mainservicesetting" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>

Despite these configurations, the custom extension attributes are not being included in the token issued during login. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I didn't notice the part where you write the extension claims to the user. Did you add them to the AAD write technical profile?

Yep, I added them to the "AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId".

Hmm, do you have Application Insights tracing set up? That and the Azure AD B2C extension for VS Code could assist here, as you could see what claims exactly were read from the user etc.

No, I haven't set up application insights.  I will set it up and take a look, thanks!
